# I get an Sql syntax error with Liquibase when I want to add a new column with conditional value

Tags: postgresql, syntax, liquibase

## Context

### Goal

I want to add a new column in a table.
I also want all existing columns to have a default value, depending on another column's value in another table.

### What I have

I have created a new changelog file :

[image]

### Issue

When I do a clean/install, I get the following error :

[image]

What have I done wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing your SQL update statement with the below one and check if it works:

```
update assignment set location = 'SITE_TSN' from requirement where (requirement.id = assignment.requirement_id and requirement.location = 'INTRAMUROS');
```

In postgres when we want to update data in a table based on values in another table, we can use PostgreSQL UPDATE JOIN syntax :

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.c1 = new_value
FROM t2
WHERE t1.c2 = t2.c2;
```

To join to another table in the UPDATE statement, you specify the joined table in the FROM clause and provide the join condition in the WHERE clause. The FROM clause must appear immediately after the SET clause.

For each row of table t1, the UPDATE statement examines every row of table t2. If the value in the c2 column of table t1 equals the value in the c2 column of table t2, the UPDATE statement updates the value in the c1 column of the table t1 the new value (new_value).

For a detailed example of this JOIN syntax, please visit [this link](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-update-join/#:%7E:text=To%20join%20to%20another%20table,every%20row%20of%20table%20t2%20.).